# Select most inner of equivalent rules in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap there is this mixin that creates various background color classes.
I modified it to also change the text color automatically. Since this change is only applied to the same element that has the class, I added that huge selector that selects all headings and paragraphs within the parent class to fix the color.

```
@mixin bg-variant($parent, $color) {
 #{$parent} {
  background: $color !important;
  color: color-yiq($color);

  p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6, .display-1, .display-2, .display-3 {
   &:not(.input-group-text) {
    color: color-yiq($color);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

**There is a second mixin, but for gradients, called bg-gradient-variant.**

But there is a problem when I have the following code structure:

```
<div class="bg-gradient-success">
 <div class="bg-secondary">
  <p>Some text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

The paragraph gets the color of **bg-gradient-success**, instead of **bg-secondary**, because the gradient mixin is defined after the normal mixin. Changing this order fixes this case but breaks others. Is there a way to automatically increase specificity in the inner class (not a hacky one use way) to make the color appropriate to the most inner class?

Comment: Can you just include reference to the other mixin in each of the two mixins, so you end up with selectors like `.bg-gradient-success .bg-secondary p {}` and `.bg-secondary .bg-gradient-success p {}`? Is that not sufficiently abstract/does it cause other problems?

Comment: Doesn't that just put the problem one level above?

gradient-success, secondary, gradient-success, p. This still matches with any of these two rules, and will get whichever is written last

Comment: If that is a possibility then perhaps you could also throw in the immediate child selector like `.bg-gradient-success > .bg-secondary > p`, which would be quite specific and effectively apply to whatever the last two classes before the `p` are, regardless of what is above them in the DOM. If things could be more complicated than that, then I think you'll have to update your question with more info about possible scenarios and what the outcome should be.

Comment: All text inside a background class (bg-* or bg-gradient-*) gets a specific color based on the color of the background that class provides. Since those classes can be nested (a div inside another div, with different background classes), the most specific one (as in, the one deeper inside the tree), should be applied to the text.